# Loading Mesh with AssetManager libGDX

Tags: java, android, loading, libgdx

I am trying to pre-load my `Mesh` objects for my libGDX game during a loading screen. I have followed the process [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AssetManager) about writing my own loader. So I basically copied the libGDX `PixmapLoader` and called it `MeshLoader`. The only problem is that because it is asynchronous, the OpenGL context is not available when the `Mesh` is created. Does anyone have any idea how I can asynchronously load a `Mesh` with `AssetManager`? I have successfully used the `SynchronousAssetLoader` instead of `AsynchronousAssetLoader` but this causes a lag in my loading screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see AssetLoadingTask API, update() method (used by AssetManager)

```
 /*Updates the loading of the asset. In case the asset is loaded with an   
 * AsynchronousAssetLoader, the loaders AsynchronousAssetLoader#loadAsync(AssetManager, String, AssetLoaderParameters) 
 * method is first called on a worker thread. 
 * Once this method returns, the rest of the asset is loaded on the rendering
 * thread via AsynchronousAssetLoader#loadSync(AssetManager, String, AssetLoaderParameters).
```

So, you **can't load a Mesh completely asynchronously** as you load a Pixmap because the later is not an openGL asset.

You could copy `TextureLoader` which loads the pixel data asynchronously (like the pixmap) and then creates the texture on the rendering thread, synchronously.

The best you can do is **calculate your vertices/indices asynchronously and do the binding synchronously.**

**Edit**
  For those who don't read comments... In case, you are using the ObjLoader to load big meshes you can follow Kieran approach given in the 3rd comment.

Comment: Thanks, oh well, I figured as much. I created a loader for at least reading the .obj files into a `String` and from there I can just create my Mesh synchronously and live with the blocking on the rendering thread.

Comment: Take a look at ObjLoader source code. You can't override it because is full of static methods, but a tiny copy-paste won't do much harm! You can easily move all the string processing to the asynch thread and may be a few more lines which create the buffers.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I used the code from `ObjLoader` and did all of the work in the `loadAsync()` method and created a custom object to hold the results that I needed to create the `Mesh` object. Then I created a base class that uses my loaded vertices to create the mesh. It is all asynchronous now, and works perfectly! Thanks a lot!